# How do I make return these components using a function instead of having it embedded in the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I a trying to accomplish not have such a big chunk of code inside the return statement, so I am trying to put that piece of code in a method as shown in the second image. It is not working however, and I am only being shown the h4 tag, without any of the input fields.

**Original Code is this**

```
import { MAPS } from "../configuration";
import styles from "./MapControl.module.css";

// Control panel to switch between visibility of different maps
// Map styles are configured in configuration.js
const MapControl = ({ visibleMap, onMapChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.position}>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h4 className={styles.heading}>Map Styles</h4>
        {
          MAPS.map((map, index) => {
            return (
              <label key={index}>
                <input type="radio" name="map-name" checked={visibleMap===map.NAME} onChange={(e) => onMapChange(map.NAME)} />
                {map.LABEL}
              </label>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MapCon
```

**I tried this:**

```
import { MAPS } from "../configuration";
import styles from "./MapControl.module.css";


const MapControl = ({ visibleMap, onMapChange }) => {
    
    const displayChoices = () => {
        return(
        MAPS.map((map, index) => {
            return (
                <label key={index}>
                    <input type="radio" name="map-name" checked={visibleMap===map.NAME} onChange={(e) => onMapChange(map.NAME)} />
                    {map.LABEL}
                </label>
            );
        }));
    }
  return (
    <div className={styles.position}>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h4 className={styles.heading}>Map Styles</h4>
        {displayChoices()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MapControl;
```

MAPS is the folowing object

```
MAPS = [
    {
        NAME: "*******", // REQUIRED - Amazon Location Service Map resource name
        STYLE: "RasterEsriImagery", // REQUIRED - String representing the style of map resource
        LABEL: "SatelliteView" // REQUIRED - Text to be displayed for the map in the layer control box
    },{
        NAME: "******",
        STYLE: "VectorEsriStreets",
        LABEL: "Street View",
    }
];
```

Comment: Was it working before you moved it to a function?

Comment: I can't see any reason why this wouldn't work the same.. Can you share the value of `MAPS`?

Comment: Yes it was working before, the value of MAPS has been added. As extra info as well, the values in the array returned are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The code/data you've provided in your question does work as expected. I've included a running example below.

You'll need to be absolutely sure that this is the code you're running while experiencing the behavior described. If it is, then there must be other missing details from the question causing it to go wrong.

```js
const MAPS = [
    {
        NAME: "NAME1", // REQUIRED - Amazon Location Service Map resource name
        STYLE: "RasterEsriImagery", // REQUIRED - String representing the style of map resource
        LABEL: "SatelliteView" // REQUIRED - Text to be displayed for the map in the layer control box
    },{
        NAME: "NAME2",
        STYLE: "VectorEsriStreets",
        LABEL: "Street View",
    }
];

const MapControl = ({ visibleMap, onMapChange }) => {
    
    const displayChoices = () => {
        return(
        MAPS.map((map, index) => {
            return (
                <label key={index}>
                    <input type="radio" name="map-name" checked={visibleMap===map.NAME} onChange={(e) => onMapChange(map.NAME)} />
                    {map.LABEL}
                </label>
            );
        }));
    }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h4>Map Styles</h4>
        {displayChoices()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MapControl visibleMap="NAME1" onMapChange={() => {}} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```